# How to resolve circular dependencies in C++

Tags: c++

```
Class A
{
}

Class B
{
    B(A* App);
}
```

Here Class A is main class which handles creation of Object B as per requirements. When Object of Class B is created objected of A is passed as argument. It all work fine if everything is defined in A.h and A.cpp but After moving code related to Class B in B.h and B.cpp I'm getting error as `syntax error : identifier 'A'`

Comment: We use forward declarations.

Comment: Forward declare Class A with `class A;` in the header of B.

Comment: There is no circular dependency in code you present. Please provide [mcve], including full error message.

Comment: you should read about forward declaration

Comment: If the forward-declarations question doesn't answer your question here, please provide a proper example, edit the question and ask for a reopen.